# Load configuration ApiModule only after user login (angular)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, swagger

I'm using ApiModule (geneterted by codegen swagger) in my angular app.
In my app.module.ts I have working  configuration but need to set configuration param apiKeys only after user login. Beceause the user recieve this param (token) after login and then I have it to set into configuration ApiModule. This param is necessary to requests that are securiet by api keys

```
export function apiConfigFactory() {


    const params: ConfigurationParameters = {
       apiKeys: {Token: '43fhih4hyghhg45'}

    };
    return new Configuration(params);
}



@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    entryComponents: [],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        ApiModule.forRoot(apiConfigFactory),
        HttpClientModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(),
        IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
        AppRoutingModule,
        AuthModule
    ],
    providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        GuardService,
        {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true},
        {provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy},
        {provide: BASE_PATH, useValue: environment.apiBasePath}
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

Comment: ofcourse i Have auth.service to handle user login .

Comment: `AuthModule` should be before `ApiModule.forRoot(apiConfigFactory)` and It is better you read on [Lazy Loading Modules](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)

Comment: sure but before user login I need too loaded this ApiModule (whitout config params)

Comment: Module config is not the right place for this. You should provide the token in a separate service and inject it

Comment: Aluan, ok I have separate service named auth and in this sevice have a login function. How to load config to AppModule from this service ?